# How can I manage sqoop target dir and result files permissions

Tags: import, permissions, sqoop, oozie, target

When I use sqoop import with target-dir parameter I have result in some folder with parts files and _SUCCESS file. How can I manage permission for this folder and files when I use sqoop. I know, we can change permissin after import, but I need to manage permission when I use only sqoop.
Ps. I am running sqoop from oozie workflow, probably I can use it to specify permissions.

Comment: Did you enable ACLs (Access Control Lists) in HDFS? If  yes, then you can define *default privileges* on a directory, so that any file/sub-dir created there afterwards inherits the privileges (and propagate them, in case of sub-dirs). Caveat 1: these are POSIX-standard ACLs, the syntax is cumbersome, e.g. `hdfs dfs -setfacl -m group:wtf:r-x,default:group:wtf:r-x /a/b/c/` Caveat 2: there is a bug in Hadoop 2 (will not be fixed before Hadoop 3) that messes the "mask" when applying default ACLs, so that W privileges are often lost, you've got to reset them periodically with `hdfs` account

Comment: Thanks. This is great issue.